# How to test whether the present build platform is Scientific Linux from within an RPM spec file?

Tags: scientific-linux, macro, rpm-spec

I would like to test if the present build platform is Scientific Linux from within a spec file. But I want this test to only return true if and only if the platform is Scientific Linux, so even the similar platforms CentOS and Red Hat Enterprise Linux fail to return a true from this test. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

On Scientific Linux 7.2 there does not appear to be a specific macro for that, as `rpm` instead only shows the `rhel` copied from:

```
# rpm --showrc | egrep -i 'sci|rhel'
-14: rhel       7
```

Apart from setting your own macro in `/etc/rpm/macros` or `~/.rpmmacros`, I guess you could write some code into the `*.spec` file that fails if the system doesn't seem right:

```
%prep
%setup -q
fgrep -q 'Scientific Linux' /etc/redhat-release || exit 1
```